# Merge Noir and Webnoir tags on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[noir](/questions/tagged/noir) and [webnoir](/questions/tagged/webnoir) are the same project by [Chris Granger](http://chris-granger.com) and refer to the same micro-framework written in Clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the questions from [webnoir](/questions/tagged/webnoir) into [noir](/questions/tagged/noir) since the word "webnoir" doesn't really appear to be used anywhere except the domain name http://webnoir.org (most likely due to domain availability) so it makes more sense to just call it Noir. That tag also already had your wiki approved for it. The other tag will be automatically destroyed within 24 hours.

Comment: I set up a synonym to go from [webnoir] to [noir] to go with your changes. If that's the domain name, I foresee it coming back otherwise.